# MVP: how to notify view about changes after de-attach

Tags: android, mvp, mosby

Let's imagine situation:

1. User click on 'Login' button and `Fragment`(`View`) call `Presenter`'s method `doLogin()`.
2. `Presenter` starts some async work and now *Boom!* app is closed(moved to recent apps)
3. `Presenter` survives and async work is still happening.
4. Async work finished while app was in the background.
5. User came back to app, but he doesn't see any notification that work is finished as view was de-attached:

   ```
           if(isViewAttached()) {
               getView().setLoaded(workResult);
           }
   ```

And I want to fix it. The only way that I see is to use `Queue<MessageToView>` and when `View` has attached again, execute every "Message".

I think that there is a library that can handle my case. So, is it? Or what pattern can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See github pages [FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20200323102407/http://hannesdorfmann.com:80/mosby/summary/) section:

> Can the Presenter and its view be out of sync during a screen
> orientation change?
>
> Excellent question. Mosby assumes that all interaction from Presenter
> with the View happens on android’s main UI thread. Hence the answer is
> no that cannot happen since screen orientation changes are executed on
> the main UI thread as well. So either is a screen orientation executed
> completely (view reattached) or the presenter invokes the views method
> after view is reattached since both run on main UI thread or the
> presenter invokes the views methods before starting screen orientation
> change.

So as long as your Presenter invokes View methods on main UI thread everything works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Fragment's `onResume()` lifecycle method, and then call something like `presenter.updateViews()`

Comment: Thank for sharing your idea, but I want to update View only if it needed, not every time that Fragment resumed. `Queue<MessageToView>` is more elegant solution for this case. Because there I can check `if(!queue.isEmpty()) { *update_view_swith_messages(Runnable)_ }` But I looking for a library that does It even more elegant :)